# Set pointer in class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, function-pointers, sfml

i'm new to c++, and i start a project with SFML. I  need a class that can handle sprite, so i do:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
class Particle
{
private:
    sf::Sprite **sprite;
public:
    Particle(sf::Sprite* sprite)
    {
        this->sprite=&sprite;
        
    };
    ~Particle();

    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f newPos)
    {
        **sprite.setPosition(newPos);
    }
};
```

i want to access certain sprite with pointer, and set that sprite to class private variable, but i meet an error "expression must have class type but it has type "sf::Sprite **". The sprite variable need to be accessed by all the function so, i want to set it locally to this class. Is there a  better way to do this?

Comment: Why pointer to pointer? That makes no sense. Especially since the pointer will be invalid (you make `this->sprite` point to the ***local*** variable `sprite` which will cease to exist once the `Particle` constructor ends).

Comment: `(*sprite)->setPosition(newPos)`. But really, remove the double pointer, there's no reason for it here.

Comment: Additionally `sf::Sprite` is a lightweight object. There is no need to use even 1 pointer. Just store it by value.

Comment: @HattedRooster i need to use the sprite locally in particle class. How to use the sprite pointer outside the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because

```
**sprite.setPosition(newPos);
```

is the same as

```
**(sprite.setPosition(newPos));
```

That is, you try to dereference what `sprite.setPosition(newPos)` *returns*.

To solve that error (leaving the other problem I already mentioned in a comment) you need to dereference the pointer variable itself:

```
(*sprite)->setPosition(newPos);
```

Comment: `sprite` is a pointer to a local (dead) variable as you mentioned yourself. I don't see how an answer not dealing with that fact could be useful.